# Arduino program gets stuck when two interrupt sources are triggered at the same time on the same pin

Tags: arduino, interrupt

I am using the RTC RV-8523 to generate countdown and alarm interrupts. The RTC **uses the same output pin for both interrupt sources**

In my program, every time that the Arduino interrupt pin detects an interrupt, it jumps into a routine that reads the content of a certain control register (Control_2) in the RTC and checks the status of both, the alarm flag (AF = 1) and the countdown flag (CTAF = 1) to find out which source triggered the interrupt. After that, the program jumps into a function that modifies certain variables and increments the index of an array to point to the next phase (see program details below)

Everything is working fine as long as the alarm and countdown interrupt are triggered at different points of time. The problem comes when they trigger at the same time. When that is the case, the system seems to remain in the 'manageSystem' function because the interrupt pin does not come back to high (when the interrupt flag in the RTC is cleared, it releases the interrupt pin). See oscilloscope capture just below the code.

Does anyone have an idea why this is not working properly? Thanks in advance

```
RV8523  RTC;                            // Create an instance of RV8523

volatile bool AlarmFlag = 0;          // 'AlarmFlag' variable to keep track of alarm interrupts
volatile bool CountdownFlag = 0;      // 'CountdownFlag' variable to keep track of countdown interrupts


uint8_t   CountdownArray [] = {  30,   5,  20,  10 };    // Number of time units that the Countdown timer has to remain in each phase
bool    PinX_StatusArray [] = {   0,   0,   1,   1 };    // Status of PinX in each phase
bool    PinY_StatusArray [] = {   0,   1,   1,   0 };    // Status of PinY in each phase
//  ArrayIndex (Phase) ·········· 0 ·· 1 ·· 2 ·· 3 ··

uint8_t ArrayIndex = 1;       // Start in phase 1


void checkInterruptSource(void);
void manageFogger(void);

void setup()
{
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), interruptRoutine, FALLING);  
  
  // Force a "manageSystem" cycle at connection time
  CountdownFlag = ON;
  manageSystem();
}

void loop()
{

}

void interruptRoutine ()
{
  checkInterruptSource();
  manageSystem();
  return;
}



void checkInterruptSource(void)
{
  uint8_t val;
  val = RTC.readRTCRegister (Control_2);    // Read RTC Control_2 register prior to check the interrupt flags

  if ( val & 0b01000000 )                   // Check if the Countdown Timer A interrupt flag has been set
  {
    CountdownFlag = ON;                     // Countdown timer A interrupt flag set
    RTC.clearFlag (Control_2, CTAF);        // Clear CTAF to capture a new countdown event
  }
  else if ( val & 0b00001000 )              // Check if the Alarm interrupt flag has been set
  {
    AlarmFlag = ON;                         // Alarm interrupt flag set
    RTC.clearFlag (Control_2, AF);          // Clear AF to capture a new alarm event
  }
      
  return;
}

void manageSystem(void)
{  
  if (AlarmFlag)
  {
    RTC.setAlarm (Hour, Min);           // Set next alarm
    RTC.clearFlag (Control_2, AF);      // Clear AF to capture a new alarm event
    AlarmFlag = OFF;                    // Clear 'AlarmFlag' variable
  }
  else if (CountdownFlag)
  {
    if( ArrayIndex >= sizeof(CountdownArray))                 // Make 'ArrayIndex' circular
    ArrayIndex = 0;

    digitalWrite (Pin_x, PinX_StatusArray [ArrayIndex]);        // Mirror to Pin_x the status of PinX_StatusArray [ArrayIndex]
    digitalWrite (Pin y, PinY_StatusArray [ArrayIndex]);        // Mirror to Pin_y the status of PinY_StatusArray [ArrayIndex]
    
    RTC.clearFlag (Control_2, CTAF);                            // Clear CTAF to capture a new countdown interrupt;
    CountdownFlag = OFF;                                        // Clear 'CountdownFlag' variable
    ArrayIndex ++;                                              // 'ArrayIndex' points to the next phase in the behavior table
  }
  return;
}
```

[Oscilloscope capture of the interrupt pin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deuZl.png)

Comment: ArrayIndex -> when it gets over 3, you'll be accessing arrays out of their bouds

Comment: You are right but I have already this in the code. I have just forgotten to put in the code above: 

if( ArrayIndex >= sizeof(CountdownArray))                
      ArrayIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

1. out of bound access because of ArrayIndex can be more than 3
2. because of `else if` you won't clear second flag and interrupt signal from the RTC probably stays LOW. And as you are checking FALLING only, your IRS handler won't get called ever again..

Comment: Thanks @KIIV, the 'else if' was the issue. When I exchange it with an 'if', the program continues. I have found out I had also another 'else if' wrongly placed producing another bug. I have reviewed again how 'else if' works because I have realized, I have misunderstood its functionality.